# Pressure Difference with respect to Surface Tension

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension

Suppose we have a drop on a flat surface of radius $R$ and volume $V$. Then by a standard force balance argument we can relate the surface tension ($\sigma$) and the pressure difference ($\Delta P$) of the liquid gas interface as:

$$2\pi R\sigma =\pi R^2 \Delta P$$
Or

$$\Delta P =\frac {2\sigma}{R}$$

Now consider a drop of the same volume $V$ suspended by a thin string of radius $L$. Assuming that the drop fully wets the string (so that the contact angle between the drop and the string is $\theta=0$, and that the drop symmetrically covers an axial section of the string throughout its rotation (I.e. if you rotate the string with the drop on it, it should look the same), then is it possible to estimate the pressure difference between the liquid and gas interface mathematically? Further (if or if not), is the pressure difference $\Delta P$ in this case greater or less than the pressure difference considered above for a drop on a flat surface? Further for the sake of simplicity we can assume negligent gravitational effects.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a sketch?

Comment: I have added a sketch. Hopefully that makes more sense.